# Set Origin to Geometry moves objekt

Tags: blender

I wanted to set the origin in the middle of the objekt so i used the function "set origin to geometry" I thought this function moved the Origin not the Objekt

[Before Set Origin to Geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJfJw.png)

[After Set Origin to Geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge8q6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the 'Set Origin to Geometry' function will move the origin point to the 'center' of the object.

Judging by your model, I would guess this would put the origin in the center of the ring.

Using 'Set Origin to Geometry' should **not** move your object - are you certain that you did not select 'Object to Cursor' or something similar?

Also - are you certain that the 'SimpleDeform' modifier that you have applied to the object is not causing the problem? Try selecting the little monitor icon on the modifier to disable it in the viewport.

You could also try this is an alternative to set the origin to the center of the object:

1. Select your object (Left click)
2. Enter Edit mode (Tab key)
3. Select all vertices (A key)
4. Press Shift-S, select 'Cursor to selected'
5. Enter Object mode (Tab key)
6. Right-click, select 'Set origin > Origin to cursor'

Answer (score 0):

If you use animation nodes there is a bug, you need to first delet the ID key of the object, then it will work properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).